# How to prevent Android ScrollView from intercepting its parents click event

Tags: android, android-xml, android-scrollview

I know there are questions like this already with answers, but I'm not having any luck with anything, so this is a last resort.

I have a LinearLayout containing a ScrollView. I want the LinearLayout to respond to click, tap, touch whatever you want to call it, but the ScrollView is interfering, so the LinearLayout's click handler is never invoked. I don't mind sub-classing ScrollView and overriding onTouchEvent (but I don't understand what to put into it), but an alternative solution is fine too. I've tried using *requestDisallowInterceptTouch(true)* on the LinearLayout, the ScrollView and the first child of the ScrollView, but it's not working (TBH, the javadoc for that method confuses me).

If I use this override in my custom scrollview:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
}
```

...the LinearLayout does respond to taps, but scrolling is completely disabled, and every type of touch gesture results in the LinearLayout click handler being invoked. So, what do I need to do to let scrolling movements be handled as they normally would and also get the ScrollView to ignore clicks/taps?

For what it's worth, the XML looks something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"            
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        .../>

   <com.package.MyScrollView
        android:id="@+id/my_scroller"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    ...  
    ...
```

Under normal circumstances, the TextView area will detect the click registered with the LinearLayout, but the ScrollView will not.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `requestDisallowInterceptTouch(true)` unfortunately does completely the opposite of what you want to achieve. It forces all parent `ViewGroup`s including the one on which you call the method to disregard events passed to them in `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.

Normally, that is without setting setting this flag to `true`, new touch events are first passed from root to leaf all the way down the view tree which allows parents (i.e. `ViewGroups`) to intercept those events by returning `true` which redirects all following events of the same gesture to this `ViewGroup`s `onTouchEvent()` method. After a view tree leaf is reached (assuming that no one has returned `true` in `onInterceptTouchEvent()`) the event bubbles back to the root via the `onTouchEvent()` method. Again returning `true` means that the event is consumed in the view doing so and all further events will be directly passed to your `onTouchEvent()` method rather than traversing through the whole view tree. So the difference between `onInterceptTouch()` and `onTouch()` is the direction of traversal through the view tree - reading all that I'm not really sure if it is more comprehensible than the javadoc.^^

Nevertheless, to put a long story short: `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` is no solution here.

That's for the prolog. Still here? Lucky you - because there *is* a (somewhat ugly) workaround for the situation you have observed: put a `OnClickListener` on the **child** of the `ScrollView` and let it `performClick()` on your `LinearLayout` that should do the trick. This will keep the `ScrollView` in a working state (unlike your attempt to override `onTouch`), but passes all click events (and only those) to the outer `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the focusable attribute of ScrollView to false.

```
<ScrollView
   android:focusable="false"
   >
   <!-- other stuff-->
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It didn't work, nor did focusableintouchmode="false"